# replace div content ajax bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Have such code: http://in-social.name/shop/
When I click button (100 line index.html)

```
<button id="start" class="btn btn-primary btn-default">
Начать тест
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></button>
```

I need to reload #mainContainer with content of test.html #cssmenu I do this with such code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#start').on('click', function (e) {
            $( "#mainContainer" ).load('test.html #cssmenu');
        })
    });
</script>
```

but it's not working.

Comment: line 100 of what..? did you try without the space- `test.html#cssmenu` ?

Comment: @TilwinJoy  http://in-social.name/shop/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#start` element is a `button`, whose type is implicitly `submit` [(due to it being omitted)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). Therefore you need to do one of two things:

1) Prevent the default button behaviour

```
$("#start").on("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault() ... });
```

2) Convert your button into a type button

```
<button id="start" type="button"...>
```